# getting a dependency graph (inverse graph) by Spring framework

Tags: java, spring

I'm using spring framework for a java project. I'm getting a .xml file, and by the code:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext xmlApplicationContext;
xmlApplicationContext.getBeanFactory().getDependenciesForBean("name of the bean");
```

I'm getting a string array that holds all the names that current object depends on.

Can i get the opposite of the call above, meaning getting all the names of object that depends on the current object?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked further in the javadoc? I think it is the *.getDependentBeans("name of bean")* that you are looking for.